# How do I fix "Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements" messages?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I was trying to do ALU for 4 bit.
I'm getting the correct output. But, while doing `RTL Schematics` and `Technology Schematics`, I'm getting errors like this:

> Signal  missing in the sensitivity list is added for synthesis
> purposes. HDL and post-synthesis simulations may differ as a result.
>
> Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do
> not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may
> lead to timing problems.

I wrote this code:

```
module alu4bit(
    input [3:0] a, b, s,            //  a = Operand_1 , b = Operand_2, s = Select
    output reg [7:0] y , remainder, //   y = outPut
    output reg negative
 );

 always @ (s)
    begin
        case(s)
            4'b0000: begin
                        negative = 0;
                        remainder <= 0;
                        y<= a+b;                        // Addition
                    end
                              
            4'b0001: begin
                        if(a<b) begin
                            y<= b-a;
                            negative =1;
                        end                             // Substraction
                        else begin
                                negative = 0;
                                y<= a-b;
                            end
                        end
                                
            4'b0010: begin
                        negative = 0;
                        remainder <= 0;
                        y<= a*b;                        // Multiplication
                    end
                              
            4'b0011: begin
                        if(a<b) begin
                            y<= 0;
                            remainder <= a;
                        end                             // Division  a/b
                        else begin
                                y <= a/b;
                                remainder <= a - (b*y);
                            end
                        end
            default: begin
                        negative = 0;
                        remainder <= 0;                 // Default  
                        y <= 0;
                    end
                              
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

1] What is wrong in this?
2] What is Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you see the "Signal missing in the sensitivity list" message is because you only have one of the required signals in the sensitivity list of the combinational `always` block.  Change:

```
 always @ (s)
```

to:

```
 always @*
```

That syntax automatically includes everything that is needed: `s`, `a`, `b`.

The reason you see the "Latches may be generated" message is because you don't make an assignment to all signals in all branches of your `case` statement.  You did not make an assignment to `negative` in the `4'b0011` case and `remainder` in the `4'b0001` case.

---

I also see a problem here:

```
                            y <= a/b;
                            remainder <= a - (b*y);
```

You have `y` on both the RHS and the LHS of assignments in combinational logic.  This creates a combinational feedback loop.

Finally, good coding practices recommend using blocking assignments `=` instead of nonblocking (`<=`) in combo logic.